# OrmLiteAuthRepository not resolving using ServiceStack

Tags: c#, ormlite-servicestack

I'm having an issue trying to resolve "OrmLiteAuthRepository" from service stack in my Global.asax.  It appears I installed the right packages from NuGet (install-package ServiceStack) for my project.

In the same file I'm able to create, register, and auto wire my ORMMySql connection as well as configure IUserAuthRepository using InMemoryAuthRepository.

Environment wise I have visual studio 2013 and ServiceStack 4.0.8.

Any ideas what my issue is in resolving my resolution issue with OrmLiteAuthRepository?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `OrmLiteAuthRepository` has been moved to the new **ServiceStack.Server** NuGet package in v4.

Other breaking changes have been documented in the [v4 Release Notes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Release-Notes#wiki-the-big-refactor-of-v4).